# How to allow specific scripts in order to watch videos

Tags: noscript

In order to watch videos with Tor, it seems to be necessary to turn off NoScript. However, this results in messages like transferring data from Google Analytics. So my question is: is it possible to only allow some scripts, necessary for watching videos, while disabling other, non-necessary scripts?

Answer (score -1):

There's no way to allow "just some in-page scripts": the JS itself contains tons of abilities for one script to add/load another one. So - either you block all of in-page JS, or you allow all of them.